# Get All Folder and Documents in Repository Alfresco Restful

Tags: java, api, rest, alfresco

I'm learning Alfresco. I want get all folder and documents in Repository with Restful API. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webscripts are a nice way to build your own API but in this case you should be fine with the buildin API that Alfresco provides you OOTB.

You can fetch all folders/documents using the REST APIs getDescendants call.
Please see the API spec for the exact details:

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Retrieve_tree_of_descendants_.28getDescendants.29

It returns a list of descendant objects of the specified folder for the defined number of levels in the tree.

```
GET /alfresco/service/api/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}/descendants?types={types}&filter={filter?}&depth={depth?}
```

It starts at the folder identified with the ID param and applies the optional arguments to your call. This means that you can e.g. filter by type (document, folder,etc) and define a depth to query. Using -1 returns you all levels.

Comment: I get a 404 error, the description says 
`Requested resource is not available.`.
Will i have to enable any module or install any additional web-scripts?
_My alfresco installation version is : 5.0 and i'm using the community edition_

Answer (score 1):

We can create restfull services using webscript of alfresco.For understanding webscript you can follow below link.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts

For creating webscript for listing folders below are the file which you will need to create.

**1.list-folders.get.desc.xml**

```
<webscript>
  <shortname>Folder Listing Utility</shortname>
  <description>Java-backed implementation of listing folder contents
  </description>
  <url>/javadir/{folderpath}?verbose={verbose?}</url>
  <authentication>user</authentication>
</webscript>
```

**2.list-folders.get.html.ftl**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Folder ${folder.displayPath}/${folder.name}</title>
  </head>
 <body>
   <p>Alfresco ${server.edition} Edition v${server.version} : dir</p>
  <p>Contents of folder ${folder.displayPath}/${folder.name}</p>
  <table>
   <#list folder.children as child>
   <tr>
   <td><#if child.isContainer>d</#if></td>
   <#if verbose>
     <td>${child.properties.modifier}</td>
     <td><#if child.isDocument>
       ${child.properties.content.size}</#if></td>
     <td>${child.properties.modified?date}</td>
   </#if>
   <td>${child.name}</td>
   </tr>
   </#list>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

The web script description specifies a URI template containing the tokens {folderpath} and {verbose?}. The folderpath token represents the folder to list and the verbose URI argument specifies whether a verbose listing is required or not. The HTML response template renders the contents of the specified folder, taking into account the verbose flag. It does this by accessing the web script model values named folder and verbose.

You need to put above files inside below path.

Company Home > Data Dictionary > Web Scripts Extensions > org

Answer (score 1):

List of documents and folders can be obtained using below endpoints.

```
GET /alfresco/service/slingshot/doclib/doclist/{type}/site/{site}/{container}

        type = documents or folders
        container = documentLibrary
```

Reference :

Browser available Webscripts here:

```
http://server:port/alfresco/service/index/all
```

Document List Webscript

```
http://server:port/alfresco/service/script/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get
```

Alfresco Version : Community v5.0.0