# Retrieve content details from alfresco with rest API

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new in alfresco, I want to get all content/document details from alfresco with rest API. From Alfresco document I have used following rest url.

`GET /alfresco/service/api/metadata?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/c58f4bc2-82d6-477‌​f-94d1-79cffc150c33`

In this url I got one content details only, but i need all the child content id's using rest API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webscript you want is:

```
GET /alfresco/service/api/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}/children
```

An example request is:

```
/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/b4cff62a-664d-4d45-9302-98723eac1319/children
```

If you want all descendants, not just all direct children then you'll have to create your own webscript as in [Get All Folder and Documents in Repository Alfresco Restful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206322/get-all-folder-and-documents-in-repository-alfresco-restful)